# How to pass html for a link_to block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to pass a `link_to` block with html but can't get it. I tried some other ways with no luck so I will use my original code:

```
<% link_to survey_path(survey), :class => "button" do %>
   <span>add questions to <%= survey.name %></span>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't show the `:class` though.

What needs to be corrected?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to add `=` to make it `<%= %>`

```
<%= link_to survey_path(survey), :class => "button" do %>
   <span>add questions to <%= survey.name %></span>
<% end %>
```

> In the view code in Rails 3 applications it’s sometimes necessary to
>   use <%= instead of <% at the beginning of blocks that output content,
>   such as form_for.

Since it's just a span, why don't you just do

```
<%= link_to "add questions to #{survey.name}", survey_path(survey), :class => "button" %>
```

Comment: Check the generated HTML, then figure which tag needs to be styled and add the class to that tag

Comment: Silly me, I didn't have any styles on that class name. I like your extra suggestion. Thank you.